# How to format PostgreSQL Query result to extract GeoJSON object from associative array with PHP?

Tags: php, postgresql, geojson

So, I'm trying build a simple mapping application with Leaflet and PostGIS. I have a shapefile of points stored in my PostgreSQL database. I am able to query the layer in PGAdmin and produce valid results and I have a simple php script that connects and executes the query. Where I'm stuck is how to format the query results to GeoJSON for the map client.

The result of running `pg_fetch_all` on the returned results is an associative array with my GeoJSON object inside like so

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [row_to_json] => {"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[8.697130556,50.123908333,108.5]},"properties":{"id":3,"photo":"/Users/Nizz0k/Desktop/Peng/IMG_3475.jpeg","type":"Quote"}}
```

My PHP skills are not great, so I'm not sure how to extract the object from within the array. I've seen several tutorials which show people recreating the GeoJSON in php, but this seems redundant as it's already being formatted by the database and being delivered formatted.

```
$result = pg_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . pg_last_error());
$geodata = pg_fetch_all($result);
print_r($geodata);
```

The above is my code so far.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to get the row_to_json data and convert into array?

Comment: exactly. I'm a bit confused about why it's getting wrapped in an array.

Comment: _“I'm a bit confused about why it's getting wrapped in an array”_ - because that’s what `pg_fetch_all` _does_, it returns an array containing all the selected records.

Comment: `$geodata[0]['row_to_json']` should work fine, no? (If you are actually expecting to get multiple records at any time, then you should of course loop over the array, instead of accessing a specific element directly via index/key.)

Comment: ok, is there another fuction that will just get the geojson? the default result is just a resource id.

Comment: it seems redundant to have to unpack the whole geojson object just to make another one?

Comment: your answer above does most of what I want it. Thanks. You can post that as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: What do you want to achieve in the end? What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data is multiple you could use [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to get geodata from the array

```
$geodata = pg_fetch_all($result);
$geodata = array_map(function($item) {
   return json_decode($item['row_to_json'],true);
},is_null($geodata) ? [] : $geodata);

print_r($geodata);
```

And you will get the associative array of GeoJSON Object from database.

If you want to get json only, you could remove `json_decode`

```
return $item['row_to_json'];
```

Comment: I'll try this out, but just accessing this property gives me the valid JSON I expect $geodata[0]['row_to_json']

Comment: what do you mean?, you want json only not an decoded geoJSON object?

Comment: I want the json for a webapp. it's already packaged the way I want on the sever side, I just need to feed it to the client. I didn't know how to access the object in the array in php